# Unable to copy that prior version to newer version

Tags: shell-script

```
# in bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /oc/txa/db/
dirs=$(echo $(ls [1-9]*([0-9])_[0-9] | sort -rn | head -n 2))
# if there are no other files and directories you can use "ls |" in the line above
newer="${dirs% *}"
prior="${dirs#* }"
test -z "$newer" && exit 1
test -z "$prior" && exit 1
cp -p "${prior}/mit.sas" "$newer"/
```

Result: `cp: cannot access 15_1:/mit.sas: No such file or directory`.

Here in this script problem will rise has `15_1:/mit.sas`.  Actually will need as `15_1/mit.sas`.
Please make a quick view in this script. And suggest where should change the exact script. Is it possible to write this script at ksh?

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do instead of how you are trying to do it. Right now it take a lot of effort to work out what you're really trying to do. As a starter: [never parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 1):

The colon comes from the `ls` command, if you substitute that with `/bin/ls -d` you should get rid of them.

```
# in bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /oc/txa/db/
dirs=$(echo $(/bin/ls -d [1-9]*([0-9])_[0-9] | sort -rn | head -n 2))
# if there are no other files and directories you can use "ls |" in the line above
newer="${dirs% *}"
prior="${dirs#* }"
test -z "$newer" && exit 1
test -z "$prior" && exit 1
cp -p "${prior}/mit.sas" "$newer"/
```

Comment: •The above code need to do this
-Copy mit.sas from prior version directory to newer version directory.
 /oc/txa/db/15_1 to  /oc/txa/db/16_0.

Here prior version= 15_1
     Newer version=16_0

Comment: I updated the answer with the compleete changes for your script

Comment: Super Working Anthon. Your Great

Answer (score 0):

```
# in bash
shopt -s extglob
cd /oc/txa/db/
dirs=$(ls -d [1-9]*([0-9])_[0-9] | sort -rn | head -n 2)
# if there are no other files and directories you can use "ls |" in the line above
newer="$(echo $dirs | head -n 1)"
prior="$(echo $dirs | tail -n 1)"
test -z "$newer" && exit 1
test -z "$prior" && exit 1
cp -p "${prior}/mit.sas" "$newer"/
```

This should give you what you need (at least, I guess so, you still doesn't provide much information, you know...).